# Remove bootstrap tooltip inline style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to style bootstrap3's tooltip, but for some reasons it's inserting a inline `top` style to the markup, see below:

```
<div class="tooltip-arrow" style="top: 50%;"></div>
```

Any idea why it's inserting this markup and how can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: the tooltip is absolutely positioned, and this tells the browser where to place it. why would you want to prevent that?

Comment: The default should be `<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>` but anyway, I found the problem. Someone added bootstrap3.3's js into my file. Was on 3.2 previously. Solved by removing the 3.3 duplicate.

Comment: hmm, I don't get it. I see style="top:###; left:###" on both 3.2 and 3.3. Curious... what problem was it causing, and what changed since you removed it?

Comment: js tooltip or data attribute?

Comment: @ShawnTaylor data attribute. It's in 3.2? I don't see it in my though. Didn't require me to do anything specifically. Or maybe its the roots theme that I'm using.